# How to deploy MPI program?

Tags: mpi

MPI require I deploy mpi program to each machine. Currently, I put the mpi program in nfs, but this method has 2 issues, one is nfs has latency issue and the other is nfs not suitable for large cluster. I know that I could use some linux shell commands to sync up my program to each node, but looks like not so convenient. especially, when I change the program frequently. Is there any easy method to to that ?

Comment: If you need to copy the program to each node and have it run from its local filesystem, you need to do so. Otherwise you can run the program and have an `MPI_Barrier` at the start so all nodes synch up before they start doing their work.

Comment: How did you reach to the conclusion that "NFS is not suitable for large cluster"? We run a cluster of almost 1500 nodes and its main filesystem comes form an NFS-shared NetApp filer.

Comment: @rath MPI_Init "is a" barrier at the beginning of the program.  All ranks must enter MPI_Init before any ranks can leave.  Depending on the implementation, exactly how far into MPI_Init ranks must get will vary.  Once a rank leaves MPI_Init it can "immediately" begin using the full MPI infrastructure including MPI_COMM_WORLD, and collectives.  Depending on the state of the other ranks, there may be some synchronization issues.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with NFS or any other network filing system in large clusters. It just means your file server isn't sized for the job. If you replace NFS with anything like ssh, ftp, scripts, or whatever and change nothing else, I don't think that'll make any significant  difference. Also, if the loading time is a significant and bothersome component of the overall runtime then why use MPI in the first place?

OK, enough of playing devils advocate. One thing you can do is to have nodes load your program onto other nodes in a binary tree type arrangement. You'll need a script that will copy the executable to two other nodes along with a copy of the script, start that script running asynchronously on those nodes and then runs the executable locally. The result would be a chain reaction of copying and running spreading across the network. The only difficult bit is in choosing which nodes to copy to so that each one is visited just once. It will be a lot faster.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the nature of the application and the nature of the NFS network, using a shared file system for both the MPI implementation and the application "should" be able to scale with reasonable performance, to a point.  Keep in mind that there is some NFS caching at the node level, so multiple ranks on the same node will not each have to traverse the network to reach the files.

In general terms, I tend to advise that NFS be discontinued at about 128 nodes or 1024 ranks in favor of local installations.  That advice changes if the NFS is delivered with 10GigE, IPoIB, or if a high performance file system like SFS or GPFS is used.

If you are committed to local installations, then tools like rsync, or scp are good candidates to distribute the bits.  Script the final result.  You can even do a tar to shared, and remote command (e.g. ssh, clush) un-tar to local disc.  The "solution" only needs to be robust, not polished or elegant.

Answer (score 0):

I'll also chime in to say the NFS should be just fine in this use-case, unless you have a cluster of over 100-200 nodes.

If you just want a lightweight tool for doing many-node parallel operations, I'd suggest [pdsh](https://code.google.com/p/pdsh/). pdsh is a very common tool on HPC clusters. It includes a command called `pdcp` for doing parallel node copies, i.e.

`pdcp -w node[00-99] myfile /path/to/destination/myfile`

Where the nodenames are node00, node01, ... node99.

Similarly, you use the `pdsh` command to run a command in parallel across all the nodes. I.e.,

`pdsh -w node[00-99] /path/to/my/executable`

---

Alternatively, if you're looking for something a little less ad-hoc for doing these operations, I can recommend [Ansible](http://ansible.cc/) as an easy and lightweight configuration management and deployment tool. It's not as simple to get started as pdsh, but might be more manageable in the long run...

For example, a simple Ansible playbook to copy a tarball to all nodes, extract it, and then execute a binary might look like:

```
---
- hosts: computenodes
  user: myname
  vars:
    num_procs: 32
  tasks:
  - name: copy and extract tarball to deployment location
    action: unarchive src=myapp.tar.gz dest=/path/to/deploy/
  - name: execute app
    action: command mpirun -np {{num_procs}} /path/to/deploy/myapp.exe
```